# Is there a Heine cretierion of liminf of a function?

Tags: calculus, analysis, metric-spaces, limsup-and-liminf

Lately i've been struggling with understanding the meaning of $\liminf_{x\to x_0}f(x)$ assuming $f:X\to\mathbb C$ for $X$ a metric space, or for that matter $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$.

Could you give me some intuition to the ugly definition?
Is there a criterion using sequences in order to understand the $\liminf$?

Thanks

Comment: If they converge, $\liminf = \lim = \limsup$, else $\liminf \le \limsup$.

Comment: @AlexR: Thanks, but I know that. I just can't seem to understand what does the $\liminf$ represents, and how can I prove that a function has certail $\liminf$ (and that's why I wanted a criterion using sequences, since it is much easier to do stuff with this)

Comment: You'll have a hard time because the limit will depend on the choice of the sequence. Maybe you can prove that $$\inf \{l | l \text{is a limit of } f \text{ at } x_0\} = \liminf_{x\to x_0} f(x)$$ But don't expect much more.

Answer (score 0):

well, if you want sequences then it could go something like "there exists a sequence $x_n \rightarrow x_0$ such that $f(x_n) \rightarrow \liminf_{x_0} f$ and for any other sequence $x_n \rightarrow x_0$ with $f(x_n) \rightarrow g$ we have $g \geq \liminf_{x_0} f$

edit: by the way - if you're asking about an alternative definition it would be useful if you included the one that you know just so that I know I'm not rewriting the definition you struggle with

Comment: I see. What if I only wanted to show $a$ is $\leq \lim\inf_{x_0} f$? Would I have to show that for every $x_n\to x_0$ we have $a\leq \lim_n f(x_n)$? Or is not quite it?

Comment: yeah, that's it - for every sequence $x_n$ such that $f(x_n)$ is convergent

Comment: and also - it's a nice exercise to deduce from AlexR's definition that $\liminf_{x_0}$ is in fact a limit of some $f(x_n)$, i.e. that our definitions are equivalent

Comment: @mm-aops Nitpicking here, but I wrote an equality, my definition would be just like yours ;)

Comment: @AlexR yeah, but you have an infimum, justifying it's actually a minimum (i.e. that it's achieved) still requires an argument ^^

Comment: @mm-aops It sure does, but the argument is basically that for $x = \sup A$ for some $A\subset \Bbb R$ implies the existence of a sequence in $A$ such that $\lim_n x_n = x$.